# How do I join four MySQL tables in one statement

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my current statement without join

```
$s1 = "SELECT * 
      FROM states
      WHERE 
      statecode='".intval($getStateCode)."'
      "; 

$s2 = "SELECT * 
      FROM county 
      WHERE 
      statecode='".intval($getStateCode)."' 
      AND 
      countycode='".intval($getCountyCode)."'
      "; 

$s3 = "SELECT * 
      FROM town 
      WHERE 
      statecode='".intval($getStateCode)."'
      AND
      countycode='".intval($getCountyCode)."' 
      AND 
      towncode='".intval($getTownCode)."'"; 

$s4 = "SELECT * 
      FROM villages 
      WHERE 
      statecode='".intval($getStateCode)."'
      AND
      countycode='".intval($getCountyCode)."' 
      AND 
      towncode='".intval($getTownCode)."' 
      AND 
      villagecode='".intval($getVillageCode)."'";
```

It's possible to join all of my tables in one statement? Let me know.

Comment: Are you concerned about losing information? Like do you want states that don't have villages?

What are you really looking for? All of the villages and their town, county and state info?

This can be done, but you'll have lots of duplicate data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT *
FROM state s 
JOIN county c ON s.statecode = c.statecode
JOIN town t ON s.statecode = t.statecode AND c.countycode = t.countycode
JOIN villages v ON s.statecode = v.statecode AND c.countycode = v.countycode AND t.towncode = v.towncode
WHERE 
      s.statecode='".intval($getStateCode)."'
      AND
      c.countycode='".intval($getCountyCode)."' 
      AND 
      t.towncode='".intval($getTownCode)."' 
      AND 
      v.villagecode='".intval($getVillageCode)."'";
```

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started:

```
SELECT * FROM state s
INNER JOIN county c ON c.statecode = s.statecode
INNER JOIN town t ON t.statecode = s.statecode AND t.countycode = c.countycode
INNER JOIN villages v ON v.statecode = s.statecode AND v.countycode = c.countycode AND v.towncode = t.towncode
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try this:

```
$sql = "select * from villages V
    join town T on T.towncode=V.towncode
    join county C on C.countycode=V.countycode
    join state S on S.statecode=V.statecode
    where V.statecode='".intval($getStateCode)."'
    and V.countycode='".intval($getCountyCode)."' 
    and V.towncode='".intval($getTownCode)."' 
    and V.villagecode='".intval($getVillageCode)."'";
```